# How to enable vsts gated checkin with Git

Tags: git, build, azure-devops

How can we establish a gated checkin using vsts online and git ?

Also what happens to the commits without local repos ? ( done over browser )

Could not find this one in vsts

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1168853/Enabling-Gated-Check-in-using-Visual-Studio-Team-S

Answer (score 0):

Gated Check-in option is available only for TFVC source control repository. You need to configure branch policies for Git repositories as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

The problem with the upper approach is it works with the pull request

we need to send the **git reset --hard HEAD~** command to revert the changes then we can use **git push -f** to force push to VSTS.

and send message devs over slack for to give feedback as for why we had to remove their code.